# select a value from a link and dynamically create <a> links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template that outputs select options according to product options value names and quantity is always different.

I need to find a way to convert those select options to `<a>`, so if one of the `<a>` s get clicked the appropriate drop-down option gets selected.

What I need is similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/3/)

However again the `<a>` tags have to get created dynamically according to `<select>` and to it's options.

Select code example, select name is now always the same, it's different.

```
<select name="212" size="1"> 
<option value="White">White</option> 
<option value="Blue">Blue</option> 
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: SO you want outside links that when clicked select one of your options?

Comment: Can you show an example of the options, and how they should determine the created links?

Comment: Added select code example to the question

Comment: The id name of select dynamically changes all the time, is there a was to reference to any select element within div name 'product-options'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made an update of the fiddle you provided. Is http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/5/ what you want?

**HTML**

```
<div id="drop-down">
<form>
<select id="items" name="items">
<option value="1">Colors</option>
<option value="2">Item 1</option>
<option value="3">Item 2</option>
<option value="4">Item 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>

<a class="dynamic-link"></a>
```

**jQuery**

Skipping the first option:

```
$('#drop-down select').find('option').each(function(i) {

    if(i > 0) {

        var self = $(this);

        var link = $('<a href="#" class="dynamic-links">' + self.text() + '</a>');

        if($('a.dynamic-links').size() == 0) {

            $('body').prepend(link);

        }
        else {

            $('a.dynamic-links').last().after(link);

        }

    }

});



$('a').on('click', function() {  

    // Get the selected item:
    $('#drop-down select option:selected').attr('selected', false);
    $('#drop-down select option:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').attr('selected', true);
    $('#drop-down select').trigger('change');

});

$('#drop-down select').on('change', function() {  
    // Get the selected <option>:
    var selected = $(this).children('option:selected');
    $('a.dynamic-link').text(selected.text());
});
```

All options:

```
$('#drop-down select').find('option').each(function() {

    var self = $(this);

    var link = $('<a href="#" class="dynamic-links">' + self.text() + '</a>');

    if($('a.dynamic-links').size() == 0) {

        $('body').prepend(link);

    }
    else {

        $('a.dynamic-links').last().after(link);

    }

});

$('a').on('click', function() {  

    // Get the selected item:
    $('#drop-down select option:selected').attr('selected', false);
    $('#drop-down select option:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').attr('selected', true);
    $('#drop-down select').trigger('change');

});

$('#drop-down select').on('change', function() {  
    // Get the selected <option>:
    var selected = $(this).children('option:selected');
    $('a.dynamic-link').text(selected.text());
});
```

Comment: The id name of select dynamically changes all the time, is there a was to reference to any select element within div name 'product-options'?

Comment: I guess you mean div ID 'product-options'? `$('#product-options select')`.

Comment: In your example you reference to an ID of an select options that you know. In this case it is `<select id="items" name="items">` but my template outputs the id of select option randomly. So is there a way to apply this javascript to any `<select>` element within div id=drop-down?

Comment: This example does now work when values are not 1,2,3,4.... My values are always different names - not numbers. Can you revise it this way? Thanks

Comment: my select looks like this 

`<form>
<select id="items" name="items">
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
</form>`

Comment: In the example they didn't want links made for the first option. Do you want to skip the first option, or do you want all the options to generate links?

Comment: Do not skip the first option please

Comment: can you also add an option WITH skipping the first option?

Comment: That should do it i think.

Comment: All options works good. Thanks

Can't get 'Skipping the first option' to make it work. Can you post it to  jsfiddle please?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with the skip-first-option version. Works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the page scrolling up everytime i click on the link?

Comment: Yes there is, skip the `href="#"` attribute on the `<a>` tag. Or set the `href=""` to an actual link. If you miss the "hand" indicating that the link is clickable, apply the CSS property `cursor: pointer;` to it.

Comment: thanks i've used JS instead. I noticed when i have more that one drop-down it combines it to one. Is there a way to create separate links for each drop-down?

Comment: Absolutely! Check out this updated jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/6/) for some implementations of what we have discussed in the comments.

Comment: Hi, i can't seem to make it right. Here is my code that needs to be modified. http://jsfiddle.net/oa9epe7k/1/ here is a screenshot how i want this to be. http://oi57.tinypic.com/24eau5x.jpg

Comment: i posted it as a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231073/convert-select-values-into-links-a?noredirect=1#comment39302778_25231073